# Why does `{} + 1` get number 1 in Chrome and Firefox, but string '[object Object]1' in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, google-chrome

Addition in Javascript is really amazing.
In Chrome and Firefox, `{} + 1` equals number 1; but in Node.js, `{} + 1` equals string '[object Object]1'. On other hand, `1 + {}` equals '1[object Object]' in both browsers and Node.js.
Who can explain why `{} + 1` equals 1 in the browsers?

Comment: Especially interesting, because node and Chrome use the same base engine ...

Comment: Sidenote: `new Object()+1` or `Object.create({})+1` equals `[object Object]1` in chrome.

Comment: Quick try in the chrome console: `{}+1` => `1` but `({}+1)` => `"[object Object]1"`

Comment: @DSoul: though both use V8, node.js the chrome console just uses eval, whereas node.js just runs whatever input it gets. That's why `({}+1)` !== `{}+1` in console. When eval-ing JSON strings (which you shouldn't BTW), you need the brackets around the string, too for that very reason

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This a bit complicated. This happens, because most JavaScript engines interpret `{}` as a code block, not object. Thus `{}+1` is essentially the same as `+1`. If you do (for example)

```
({}+1})
```

then the code inside brackets `()` will be interpreted as a expression, not code block. Thus `{}` becomes an actual object.

Read this for more details:

http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/object-plus-object.html

The article also explains why it is different in Node.Js.