# weird behavior in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, object-literal

Take a look at the screenshot...

[image: screenshot]

The reason why I'm experimenting with this is because I did a simple Google search for how to check if a parameter is a function, and I found this...

```
var getClass = {}.toString;
...
function isFunctionA(object) {
    return object && getClass.call(object) == '[object Function]';
}
```

source: http://jsperf.com/alternative-isfunction-implementations/4

So what is the difference between what I'm typing out and the example source code? Why is Chrome giving an error when entering just `{}.toString`, but works fine when it is inside the parenthesis?

Comment: Not exactly duplicate, but answers the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264065/why-does-1-get-number-1-in-chrome-and-firefox-but-string-object-object/12264159#12264159

Answer (score 4, accepted):

{} at the beginning of a statement is ambiguous, is it an empty code block or an object? The definition resolves the ambiguity by defining it as a code block, to use {} at the start of a statement as an object make it an expression by enclosing it in parentheses : ({})

See also answer to [Why does accessing a property directly on an Object literal throw a SyntaxError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553792/why-does-accessing-a-property-directly-on-an-object-literal-throw-a-syntaxerror)

Comment: I'm looking at this code... http://jsperf.com/alternative-isfunction-implementations/4